# PHP How to Catch DeadlineExceededError on SendMail to continue Script execution

Tags: php, google-app-engine, exception

I have set up a script that runs daily on Google App Engine. It gets data from a database, and in a loop checks that data, and if certain conditions are met, it will send an email to a defined email address which it gets when it gets the other data. On rare occasion, this deadline error occurs:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'google\appengine\runtime\DeadlineExceededError' with message 'The API call     
mail.Send() took too long to respond and was cancelled.' in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/RealApiProxy.php:74
```

What i am looking for is simply this: how do i catch this exception so that i can continue with the execution of the script? Since it is defined as an Exception, i presume using

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    //code to check if email needs to be sent
    try {
        //send mail code
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // handling code
    }
}
```

Would allow me to deal with it, but being this is a AppEngine exception related to Timing out, it does not sound to me like one a Try block can handle. so, is it just a regular exception and the above code would guarantee execution of the full loop when this error occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, There is no way to directly deal with this Error. It is a Fatal error after all, and so the script will always stop once this occurs. There is however a workaround specific to App Engine, which is what i was looking for, [Push Queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/taskqueue/overview-push). They allow the Email to be sent out in a separate script asynchronously with no reply (fire-and-forget style). By doing so, the Fatal error occurs in an isolated instance of a secondary script, so that even if it Fatal errors out, only that single instance is affected, which means that only the one email is not sent out.

If 100 emails are supposed to send, and one Fatally errors out, now 99 are sent out instead of only 20-50 because it was in the middle.

Comment: and the task will retry, so even if there is an error, after retry 100 emails should be send.

Answer (score 1):

The [DeadlineExceededError class](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-sdk/blob/master/google/appengine/runtime/DeadlineExceededError.php) extends Error rather than Exception. You'll want to use `set_error_handler` to set the function to put your handling code in.